# Checkboxes in Multistep: Form handler differences?

Tags: 7, forms

Using D7, and checkboxes that I've added via the normal 'manage fields' interface don't stay checked. When I navigate to the next page in the form or when I save it, the values appear to be lost. The values do not display on the node itself or the form when edited again later. They are simply not present in the $form array.

As Clive pointed out, this is a known bug but it looks like it hasn't been active in a while.

It looks like a submit handler problem, since among the options "back," "save," "next," and "done" it appears that "save" actually saves the values, but that "back," "next," and "done" not only fail to save values, but actually seem to clear out any values that had been entered.

What are the practical differences between these form handlers, other than just their redirect behavior? Is there something in the differences between these submit handlers that could be causing this problem? Am I even barking up the right tree here?

Comment: What method are you using to make the node form a multistep one?

Comment: With [Multistep](http://drupal.org/project/multistep).

Comment: Looks like it's a [known bug](http://drupal.org/node/1419120)

Comment: Ooh I think I found a clue: http://drupal.org/node/1366534

Comment: Tried changing `#access` to TRUE for all submit handlers but it didn't help. I think this error is related maybe? `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`